# chrome extension не работает xhr

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь в inject.js вызвать xhr get запрос на другой сайт,  но в ответ получаю :

> Refused to connect to 'https://site.com/fsave_data.php/?request=000'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "connect-src https://websdk.moengage.com https://www.googleapis.com
>   wss://*.zopim.com wss://*.cackle.me wss://*.binomo.com
>   binomo.zendesk.com mc.yandex.ru *.intercom.io wss://*.intercom.io
>   app.getsentry.com *.kameleoon.com 'self'".

Т.е. запрос блокируется хромом. Как обойти эту блокировку?
В манифесте прописал:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://site.com; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": [
    "https://site.com/*"
  ]
```

Но не помогает(

Comment: Это не хром блокирует, а сам сайт видимо, пробовали в других браузерах?

Comment: да, это сайт блокирует.  в ошибке написано даже каким хостам можно залезать. но кажется можно обойти как-то костыльно либо проксик свой сделать.